# WebViewClient class is not working on android api level 15

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

In my class my webview is extending from WebViewClient

the code snippet is given :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    view = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.102:8086/QOSKO/"); 
    view.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebChrome());
}

private class  HelloWebChrome extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
}
```

In this i am trying to open website into my application with the help of WebViewClient class .
this code is running on android api level 8 but the same code is not running on android api level 15.

```
my ques is how to run WebViewClient class on android api level 15.
```

Comment: need more info Ru running in emulator or device. Ru checking in same network.

Comment: i m running in both and in same network.

Comment: what more info do u want plz let me know.

Comment: I mean RU getting any error like that..? can try once as make it  'return true' and run it.

Comment: yes i m getting an exception  -- java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.---this one i got in my log.

Answer (score 1):

I think ur problem is this :

```
view.loadUrl(url);
```

bcz u have load url two times first is view.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.102:8086/QOSKO/"); and other is view.loadUrl(url); in webviewchromeclient that'y exception occurs try to  remove one of line from this both one by one 
and check

Comment: Thnks for your reply @Khan but if this is reason of exception then why it is perfectly running on Android api level 8.

Comment: hey i have noticed one thing in this webview my localhost url is not working but if i run google on it it is running sucessfully.

Comment: k means problem is in url right what it contains a html file or other thing if it is html file than try with put into asset folder and than load that file

Comment: no it on local server i have to fetch it from its url like http://192.168.1.102:8086/QOSKO/

Answer (score 0):

This is an [open issues](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21177)

**sol1:** you need to add the webview to the view dinamically.
currently you are using `view = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);`

```
WebView view=new WebView(this);
```

**sol2:** Add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to the actual Activity that the Webview was contained in the Manifest. Hopefully that works for you I think.

Comment: WebView view=new WebView(this);

Comment: hey i have noticed one thing in this webview my localhost url is not working but if i run google on it it is running sucessfully

Comment: is that Url with https or http ?